# Xamarin.ios Implement Navigation drawer

Tags: xamarin.ios, navigation, drawer

I am having a problem with implementing a navigation drawer in ios. I have found the Sidebar Navigation component , flyout navigation, Monotouch.Navigation and some others.

The flyout Navigation approach works but i am finding it difficult to customize the side menu because it extends the UITableview controller. It would be easier to customize it if it was a UIViewcontroller instead.

The Sidebar Navigation allows for customiszation but selecting an item causes the app to freeze and I am unable to disable the drawer on the login screen.

Would really like some suggestions if there is an easier way to implement this or am i missing something. (Take note, the drawer should only show after the user has passed the login screen and taken to the home screen).

Comment: If know Xamarin Forms, you can refer to this.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page.If just want to do in IOS,the requirement need to custom view. (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/PhoneMasterDetailRenderer.cs).

Comment: Yes i have worked in Xamarin.Forms before but I have already started my current project in Xamarin Native. Its really strange that there is no simple way to implement a navigation drawer in Xamarin Native (iOS)

Comment: You can try this [HERE] (https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.SideMenu)

Comment: Maybe the easier way is when creating a new Xamarin.ios App, you can choose a Master-Detail App, not a Signal-Vew App.Before login the login view will cover the controller.After login ,the main controller will appear.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac's 8.1.5 (build 9) Master-Detail project template uses Tab navigation now. The Navigation drawer is not part of their project templates anymore. :-(